# Pass an instance of a class to an attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, attributes, asp.net-web-api

I have an attribute for my web api authentication:

```
public class ApiAuthenticationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private IApiAuthentication AuthenticationProvider { get; set; }

    public ApiAuthorizeAttribute(Type apiAuthorizationType)
    {
        AuthenticationProvider = (IApiAuthentication)Activator.CreateInstance(apiAuthorizationType);
    }
 ....
}
```

In this attribute i have the `IApiAuthentication` type that will do authentication logic.

For passing a concrete type of `IApiAuthentication` to the attribute I pass in the `Type` like this:

```
[ApiAuthentication(typeof(ApiAuthentication))]
```

I want to know is there a better way to do this?